# Using New APIs when Supporting Older Versions of Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, backwards-compatibility

I'm trying to add a feature for API 21+ into an app that supports back to 18. I have checks to make sure that the phone running the app is on API 21 for various methods, but I need to declare one object at the top of my activity and that's stopping the app from working on older API phones. Is there any patterns for wrapping that object so that it only gets created for devices running API 21+, and returns null for anything less than that? For context, this is for the Bluetooth advertiser, and I need this object for creating/stopping advertising:

```
private AdvertiseCallback mAdvertisingCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
    }
};
```

whereas my advertising data is in a method:

```
private void advertise( String stufftoadvertise ) {
    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isMultipleAdvertisementSupported() ) {
        BluetoothLeAdvertiser advertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

        AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                .setAdvertiseMode( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER )
                .setTxPowerLevel( AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_LOW )
                .setConnectable( false )
                .build();

        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString( getString( R.string.uuid_advertise ));
        ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( uuid );

        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeDeviceName( true )
                .addServiceUuid( pUuid )
                .addServiceData( pUuid, stufftoadvertise.getBytes( Charset.forName("UTF-8") ) )
                .build();

        advertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertisingCallback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is necessarily the best solution, but I did find a way to make this work. I just created a static class that returns a singleton of the callback, and only invoke this class when the API is 21 or higher

```
@TargetApi(21)
public class AdvertiseCallbackCreator {

private static final AdvertiseCallback mAdvertisingCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
    }
};

public static AdvertiseCallback getAdvertiseCallback() {
    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isMultipleAdvertisementSupported() ) {
        return mAdvertisingCallback;
    } else return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't instantiate the object unless you're API 21+. For example, don't do this:

```
private AdvertiseCallback mAdvertisingCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
    }
};
```

But instead, do this:

```
private class CustomAdvertiseCallback implements AdvertiseCallback {
    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
    }
}
```

And then when you need to use it, just initialize it there:

```
advertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, new CustomAdvertiseCallback());
```

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I figured. Ended up doing something similar and posted earlier.